# Counting how many times each pixel is covered in several GeoTIFFs

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, pixel

I have a few GeoTIFFs which **might** have overlap, I want to find how many times each pixel is covered in several GeoTIFFs. I thought it is best to create a heat map in Python (using GDAL or Rasterio) showing the **number or count** of available data for each pixel, in other words, if a pixel is covered by one of the GeoTIFFs put 1, if it is covered by two of them put 2, if three times put 3 and if there is no coverage at all by none put `NaN`. But how?

I worked on merging the GeoTIFFs (called *merged.tiff*) and then creating a heatmap using the below code, but it is not showing what I want.

```py
with rasterio.open('merged.tiff') as src:
    data = src.read(1)

mask = (data > 0).astype(np.uint8)
pixel_count = np.sum(mask)
heatmap = pixel_count * mask

# Plot the heatmap
plt.imshow(heatmap, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar(label='Number of Pixels Covered')
plt.title('Pixel Count Heat Map')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Con to bit mask (1/0) then mosaic with Add

Comment: I appreciate it if you could explain it further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given some overlapping rasters, for example the below three tifs:

[image]

You can use the [`rasterio.merge.merge`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.merge.html) function with the `rasterio.merge.copy_count` method.

```
from rasterio.merge import copy_count, merge

rasters = ["test1.tif", "test2.tif", "test3.tif"]

# Write out a file
merge(rasters, method=copy_count, target_aligned_pixels=True, dst_path="merge_count.tif")
# Or retrieve a numpy array and an affine transform
merge_count, transform = merge(rasters, method=copy_count, target_aligned_pixels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!